# MySQL calculate sum of columns of last "closed group"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, with (for simplicity) two fields:

```
#00 value | enabled
#01 ===============
#02 100   | 1
#03 200   | 1
#04 300   | 1
#05 0     | 0
#06 0     | 0
#07 200   | 1
#08 200   | 1
#09 200   | 1
#10 100   | 1
#11 0     | 0
#12 0     | 0
```

Each hour one record is logged.

Basically the enabled value marks a cycle, when enabled = 1, the value indicate a certain amount of power consumed (in 1 hour per line). When enabled = 0 there is still one line per hour (the value is irrelevant then).

Question:

I need to sum of all the "values" for the *last* complete cycle = sequence of enabled=1's. So in the above example #07-#10 = 200+200+200+100 = 700.

How can this be done in SQL? Maybe a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in SQL. Can you show us the SQL you're having issues with?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no last or next row, unless a column specifies the ordering.  I assume there is one in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback and input guys. In the end, I developed a solution with a stored procedure, it look like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`pleb`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(OUT power float, OUT durationMinutes float)
BEGIN

-- used to break out of the loop --
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
-- calculates power...
DECLARE hp float;
DECLARE acOn bool;
-- variables used to track one complete cycle
DECLARE acOffFound bool DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE acOnFound bool DEFAULT 0;
-- cursor should itterate over max 1day of values (5 minutes chunks = 288 chunks per day)
DECLARE sensor_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT heatingPower, inputAcOn FROM `pleb`.`sensordata` ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 288;
-- if notihing found loop should quit right away
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
-- open the cursor
OPEN sensor_cur;
-- init zero
SET power = 0;
SET durationMinutes = 0;

-- loop over the result set
calculate: LOOP
 -- put into variables
 FETCH sensor_cur INTO hp, acOn;
 -- check if I should stop
 IF finished = 1 THEN 
  LEAVE calculate;
 END IF;
-- if we already found ac off and ac on and its off again get out of loop we are finished
 IF acOffFound = 1 AND acOnFound = 1 AND acOn = 0 THEN
  LEAVE calculate;
 END IF; 
 -- wait until we see power off first
 IF acOffFound = 0 AND acOn = 1 THEN
  ITERATE calculate;
 END IF;
 -- detect if we have seen power off
 IF acOffFound = 0 AND acOn = 0 THEN
  SET acOffFound = 1;
 END IF;
 -- detect if we found an power on
 if acOnFound = 0 AND acOn = 1 THEN
  SET acOnFound = 1;
 END IF;
 -- if its on calculate
 IF acOn = 1 THEN
  SET power = power + ( (hp * 5) / (1000*60) );
  SET durationMinutes = durationMinutes + 5;
 END IF;

 -- next cycle
 END LOOP calculate;


-- get rid of the cursor
CLOSE sensor_cur;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SQL.  Here is one way:

```
select count(*), sum(value)
from t cross join
     (select max(id) as max_prev0
      from t cross join
           (select max(id) as max_1
            from t
            where id = 1
           ) t0
      where t = 0 and t.id < t.max_1
     ) t1
where t.id > t.max_prev0 and t.id <= t.max_1;
```

Note:  this assumes that you do have some 0s in the data (although it is easy to handle the `NULL` values.  It also assumes that you have a field (called `id` in this query) that handles the ordering.